# Adding content in x direction only in div

Tags: html, css

How to add content in x-direction only?

in `<div>` tag i am putting 5 to 6 images. greater to the total width of div. So it gets back to the new line after if reaches end of the width of div.

I have put

```
img
{
    float:left;
}
```

but no luck.

div's `oveflow-x:scroll;`

but no luck.

I want the images to b added horizontally instead of vertically. I want scrollbar at in the x direction to view all the images.

Where i'm missing?

HTML:

```
<div id="scrollar">
<img src="1.jpg">
<img src="2.jpg">
<img src="3.jpg">
<img src="4.jpg">
<img src="5.jpg">
<img src="6.jpg">
<img src="7.jpg">
<img src="8.jpg">
</div>
```

the width contains 5 images.after that it goes to the new line. I want all images in that line only. It should be visible by scrolling in x-direction.

Comment: Please add your html.

Comment: You need to add another wrapper element that is equal to the width of the images.

Comment: for that i need the width of that total images? So I should count with the help of javascript?

Comment: BenM .. can you just explain a bit?

Comment: Exactly, you need to know the width of the images together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to specify the width of the container or add extra markup, just tell it not to wrap.

http://jsfiddle.net/BHD5Y/

```
div#scrollar {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        <img src="img/01.jpg" alt="" width="675">
        <img src="img/02.jpg" alt="" width="675">
        <img src="img/03.jpg" alt="" width="675">
        <img src="img/04.jpg" alt="" width="675">
        <img src="img/05.jpg" alt="" width="675">
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.wrapper{
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   overflow:auto;
}

.content{
    height:450px;
    width: 3375px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}

.portfolio img{
   margin:0 12px;
   float:left;
}
```